# How to remove a character in json at specific index using js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, string, replace

I have a json code as below:

```
[  
   [  
      {  
         "title":"Shirt Front",
         "thumbnail":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_2.jpg",
         "elements":[  
            {  
               "type":"image",
               "source":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_2.jpg",
               "title":"Base",
               "parameters":{  
                  "left":325,
                  "top":329,
                  "colors":"#d59211",
                  "price":20,
                  "colorLinkGroup":"Base",
                  "fill":false
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "title":"Shirt Front",
         "thumbnail":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_1_1.jpg",
         "elements":[  
            {  
               "type":"image",
               "source":"ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_1_1.jpg",
               "title":"Base",
               "parameters":{  
                  "left":325,
                  "top":329,
                  "colors":"#d59211",
                  "price":20,
                  "colorLinkGroup":"Base",
                  "fill":false
               }
            }
         ]
      },

   ]
]
```

I need to remove the `comma` at the end of array ie. the comma before the last two characters of the json. Due to this the above json is a invalid json. I need to achieve this using JS.

Comment: Is this a string, or JS source code? You could eval it and re-encode it with `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: Remove it at the point it's generated. Doing this in JS after receiving the JSON is a hacky workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is another approach, assuming your input is a string. It finds the last index of a comma in the string, and then uses `string.splice` to assemble a new string without that comma.

```js
const JSON = `[  
   [  
      {  
         "title":"Shirt Front",
         "thumbnail":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_2.jpg",
         "elements":[  
            {  
               "type":"image",
               "source":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_2.jpg",
               "title":"Base",
               "parameters":{  
                  "left":325,
                  "top":329,
                  "colors":"#d59211",
                  "price":20,
                  "colorLinkGroup":"Base",
                  "fill":false
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "title":"Shirt Front",
         "thumbnail":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_1_1.jpg",
         "elements":[  
            {  
               "type":"image",
               "source":"ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_1_1.jpg",
               "title":"Base",
               "parameters":{  
                  "left":325,
                  "top":329,
                  "colors":"#d59211",
                  "price":20,
                  "colorLinkGroup":"Base",
                  "fill":false
               }
            }
         ]
      },

   ]
]`

lastComma = JSON.lastIndexOf(',')

const JSONnew = JSON.slice(0, lastComma) + JSON.slice(lastComma + 1, JSON.length)

console.log(JSONnew)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use eval, but know that it is dangerous, this code is valid JavaScript

```
const json = `[  
   [  
      {  
         "title":"Shirt Front",
         "thumbnail":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_2.jpg",
         "elements":[  
            {  
               "type":"image",
               "source":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_2.jpg",
               "title":"Base",
               "parameters":{  
                  "left":325,
                  "top":329,
                  "colors":"#d59211",
                  "price":20,
                  "colorLinkGroup":"Base",
                  "fill":false
               }
            }
         ]
      },
      {  
         "title":"Shirt Front",
         "thumbnail":"http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_1_1.jpg",
         "elements":[  
            {  
               "type":"image",
               "source":"ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_1_1.jpg",
               "title":"Base",
               "parameters":{  
                  "left":325,
                  "top":329,
                  "colors":"#d59211",
                  "price":20,
                  "colorLinkGroup":"Base",
                  "fill":false
               }
            }
         ]
      },

   ]
]`

const validJsArray = eval(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.stringify` will clean that up for you.

```
var my_cool_object = [
        [
            {
                "title": "Shirt Front",
                "thumbnail": "http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_2.jpg",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "type": "image",
                        "source": "http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_2.jpg",
                        "title": "Base",
                        "parameters": {
                            "left": 325,
                            "top": 329,
                            "colors": "#d59211",
                            "price": 20,
                            "colorLinkGroup": "Base",
                            "fill": false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "title": "Shirt Front",
                "thumbnail": "http://ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_1_1.jpg",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "type": "image",
                        "source": "ipadd/pub/media/catalog/product//b/l/blue-back_1_1.jpg",
                        "title": "Base",
                        "parameters": {
                            "left": 325,
                            "top": 329,
                            "colors": "#d59211",
                            "price": 20,
                            "colorLinkGroup": "Base",
                            "fill": false
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
        ]
    ];
    var valid_json_string = JSON.stringify(my_cool_object);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var json = [ ...  ]
console.log(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(json)));
```